# SQL - can we combine AND operator and NOT IN?

Tags: sql

can we combine the AND operator and NOT IN in mysql? for example:

```
WHERE x AND y NOT IN ( SELECT X,Y
                   FROM ....

                  );
```

Is the syntax correct?

Comment: Well, when you run it, do you get an error?

Comment: Which database? Some support something like this, and some don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not this is possible depends on the database server you use. Some databases (eg PostgreSQL) support row values, which allow you to do this:

```
where (x, y) in (select colX, colY from ....)
```

Otherwise you can do something like

```
where exists (select 1 from ... where colX = x and colY = y)
```

Answer (score -4):

yes but you should add "AND" operator to your query:

```
WHERE x AND y AND NOT IN ( SELECT X,Y FROM ....
```

Comment: Correct syntax is `<column or value> [NOT] IN (....)`, so your suggestion is invalid.

Comment: Sorry my mistake... Its because of rush :)

Comment: don't rush, it's not a race

Comment: is this one good?  WHERE (x AND y) NOT IN (SELECT x,y FROM...);

Comment: @ali why do you think this is a site for running queries for you? Stop being lazy, run your own queries. If you find errors, _then_ ask about them